# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 when trying to send data from Swift to PHP

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I'm trying to send data from Swift to PHP but whatever i try, it won't work. The latest error i'm getting is the

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start
>   with array or object and option to allow fragments not set."' and
>   'UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or
>   object and option to allow fragments not set.}' errors.

I have no idea where the problem is, as i validated my JSON and the PHP side is working when using Postmen. So the problem has to be in the Swift code i guess..
This is my Swift code:

```
    let payload = try! JSONEncoder().encode(bon)
    let payloadString = String(data:payload, encoding: .utf8)!

    //URL to our web service
    let URL_SAVE_TEAM = URL(string:"http://trinto.kuppeveld.xyz/API/createteam.php")

    //creating NSMutableURLRequest
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL_SAVE_TEAM!)

    //setting the method to post
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    //adding the data to request body
    request.httpBody = payloadString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    //creating a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
                        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error is \(error!)")
            return;
        }

        print("-----")
        print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!)
        print("-----")

        //parsing the response
        do {
            //converting resonse to NSDictionary
            let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            //parsing the json
            if let parseJSON = myJSON {

                //creating a string
                var msg : String!

                //getting the json response
                msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?

                //printing the response
                print(msg)                        
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }                  
    }
    //executing the task
    task.resume()
```

When i print payloadString it returns the JSON as following:

```
{"datum":"11-12-2017","winkel":"jumbo","producten":[{"prijs":"2.50","naam":"ham"},{"prijs":"1.20","naam":"brood"}],"tijd":"15:07"}
```

And to be sure, here is my PHP code (which works with Postmen, as i mentioned):

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$array = json_decode($json, true);

echo $json;
var_dump($array);
```

`var_dump($array)` return NULL for some reason, but when i use Postmen it has no problem giving back the JSON as i inserted.

Has anybody got a clue how to fix my problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When converting response to dictionary try using `.jsonObject` method with `.allowFragments` option instead of `.mutableContainers`

Comment: Thanks, it did give back some data in Swift. However, still nothing in PHP. i've updated my PHP to send it directly to my SQL database but now get the error:    `Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "No value." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=No value.}`